# DotNetNuke 6.0 setting APIKey and Secret for Authentication Module

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, dotnetopenauth, api-key

I install a authentication module from DNN superadmin but i need to set up API Key and Secret from superadmin.

How will I set it up using Setting.aspx page of authentication module and also fetch value on login page of module?

Answer (score 1):

You do this from the Admin/Extensions page, choose the Authentication provider you need to configure, click on the Pencil next to the auth provider, this will open up the settings.

You do this per portal, you can also enable/disable other providers from there.